# Обучение сетки на дополнительных данных

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

У меня есть сетка для классификации текстов. Я ее обучил на 47 классах.
Суть проблемы в том, что в любой момент я хочу например до обучить ее на дополнительных классах (48,49 и т.д.), но чтобы веса прошлых классов сохранились.
Как это правильно делать? дайте совет пожалуйста.